# It is not launching the exe while inserting the CD inside the CD drive

Tags: c#, autorun

Autorun.inf file is not working to lunch the .exe in winforms.
I am writting the CD/DVD from export functinallity in my C# code for that I am using API such as

```
IMAPI2.Interop;
IMAPI2.MediaItem;
```

but using these api's I can wtrite respective dll and exe inside CD/DVD also I am adding the Autorun.inf file to CD but it is not launching the exe while inserting the CD inside the CD drive

Autorun.inf

```
[autorun]
open=Lite\CDWritterApp.exe
icon=Lite\CDWritterApp.exe,0
action=Start ShellRun-CD
```

Comment: Does it not 'autorun'? or does it not work when you right-click it? autorunning by default had been disabled for security reasons.

Comment: @Petesh Yes its not autorun the disk while inseting the disc into drive

Answer (score 2):

Autorun can simply happen to be blocked on target computer. You never have any guarantee that it will really "auto-run" anything.

If you are 100% sure that the computer doesn't have the autoruns blocked (i.e. insert any other CD/DVD that has Autorun.inf - do they run?), check if the exe files are really at 'X:\Lite" folder where X: is the drive of you CD/DVD.

If the files are in the right place, then you can check with [ProcessMonitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see if Windows really tries to execute them. Set the ProcMons' filters to "Path contains Autorun.inf -> inlude" and "Path contains CDWriterApp -> include" and insert your CD.

If ProcMon doesn't show that Autorun.inf is being read - well, that's strange, check if you have the filename really right and unblock the autoruns in your OS.

If ProcMon doesn't show that the CDWrterApp is being read, or shows 'not found' - wrong name? wrong directory? file missing?

If ProcMon shows that CDWriterApp is being read, and shows that the new process is started and then immediatelly exists - you've screwed up the app and it starts, but crashes immediatelly.

Of course, there are some other options and causes, but you should be able to trace them.

Comment: I tried all the way but haven't yet able to resolve the problem

Comment: (1) Have you checked in the Registry and looked for any keys that disable the autorun feature? (2) try inserting the disk then right-clicking on it and select "autoplay" that should show up in the context menu of the CD -- does the app start then? (mind that you have to rightclick on the DRIVE, like E:, not on any folder inside)